# getting the error `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 35887]` while working with fer2013.csv

Tags: keras

i am trying to build a facial emotion recognition project. and while i m at it, i m getting `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 35887]` this error but i m clueless.
my code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf


data = pd.read_csv('fer2013.csv')

# Extract images and labels from the dataset
images = data['pixels'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x.split(' '), dtype='float32').reshape(48, 48, 1))
labels = data['emotion']

# Convert labels to categorical format
labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=7)

# Normalize pixel values to range [0, 1]
images /= 255.0


images_rgb = np.tile(images, (1, 1, 1, 3))


train_images, test_images, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(images_rgb, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(48, 48, 3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
pretrained_model.trainable = False  # Freeze pre-trained layers


x = pretrained_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')(x)


model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=pretrained_model.input, outputs=output)


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)


test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print("Test accuracy:", test_acc)
```

any help is appreciated.